# INSERT INTO-Statement with PHP-Variable and SELECT-Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I´m trying to insert a current SELECT-Statement into an Database table with an PHP-variable. It works by this way without the variable:

`mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (column) SELECT column FROM table1");`

Did anyone have a idea how I can fix it?

PHP: 5.3.10 and mysql-databse

Comment: Glad it worked , Can you post your _code_ in which you tried with the variables ?

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated, use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: @Bart Friederichs you don't know what PHP version he is using. Also it's unrelated to the question.

Comment: Too many people are too quick to point out using MySQLi or PDO

Comment: do you need to know how to do it with a php variable? right?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use mysql_insert_id() to get the last inserted ID value and try insert query separately.

```
<?PHP
$lastId = mysql_insert_id();
$query = mysql_query("Your Select Query with $lastId");
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this would help me if I only have to add one row into the table but it could be more than one. Can I modify your solution?

Comment: yeah,you u can use it in an array to store multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $sample="SELECT column FROM table1";  // your select query
$query="INSERT INTO `table` (column) $sample";
mysqli_query('database connection code',$query);
```

Let me know if any problem arises.

Comment: I need to know how can I insert both variants in a statement.

Comment: both variants.. I didn't get you